# Calling class functions through a pointer to the class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Suppose we have the following class:

```
    class Cell
    {
    private:
        int x;
        Cell *next;
    public:
        Cell(int a)
        {
              x = a;
        }
        int getX()
        {
              return x;
        }
        Cell *getNext()
        {
              return next;
        }

     };
```

as well as the fallowing class:

```
    class Snake
    {
    private:
        Cell *tail;
    public:
        Snake()
        {
            Cell newCell(10);
            tail = &newCell;
        }
        Cell *getTail()
        {
            return tail;
        }
    };
```

and this is our main function:

```
      int main()
      {
           Snake newSnake;
           int a = newSnake.getTail()->getX();
           cout << a << endl;
           return 0;
       }
```

when I execute my code I get the output:

```
      -858993460
```

when the output is expected to be:

```
       10
```

and I can't seem to figuer out what the problem is, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 tail = &newCell;
```

this line will cause undefined behaviour. after it goes out of scope `newCell` is destroyed and `tail` still pointing there where could be anything (correct value, 0, random value or....)

**To solve your problem:**

First, I believe the whole design is broken and need to be reviewed. However, I will correct the mistake with less possible changes without touching the design.

change this:

```
   Snake()
    {
        Cell newCell(10);
        tail = &newCell;
    }
```

to:

```
   Snake()
    {
        Cell newCell(10);
        tail = new Cell(10);;
    }
```

And add this:

```
   ~Snake()
    {
        delete tail;
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually working on a much bigger project with a code similar to my example above, except my project wont work

Comment: Then please edit your question with minimal possible information that we can reproduce your problem and help you with it

Comment: I would, but my project has three classes and each one has a .h and a .cpp file, that's six different files and add one more for my main function, so I couldn't specify my problem, I had to make a simple example.

Comment: Your small example has nothing wrong.. so you would try to put more relative example

Comment: As samll as possible that problem can be reproduced :)

Comment: I did it :) what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be the correct way. When you type

```
ptr->getX()
```

its the same thing as

```
(*(ptr)).getX()
```

You can always look at the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) for the `->` operator too.